# Android reflection ClassNotFound

Tags: android, reflection, classnotfound

I am new in Android programming. I want to invoke a method in the class BatteryService by reflection. However, the following code fails above Android 5.0, including the newest Android 6.0.1, though it succeeds in Android 4.3. I have googled for days. But I cannot find any useful answers.

```
try{
        Class myclass = Class.forName("com.android.server.BatteryService");
   } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("xx", "ClassNotFound!");
   }
```

I have checked the source of Android 4.3, 5.0 and 6.0.1, and I am sure that the class BatteryService is in com.android.server. BTW, the modifier of BatteryService is public.

When running the above code, Android 5.0+ report an exception that the Class cannot be found. But the code works in Android 4.3. I wonder there are any new features introduced in Android 5.0 to preventing reflection?

Anyone knows the reason. Thanks a million!

Comment: Could you please also post the relevant part of the stack trace for our reference? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably classloader doesn't know that class. App classloader and system classloader are not same.

---

EDITED

When starting systemserver, class path has set.
So, probably system app doesn't have this classloader.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/com/android/internal/os/ZygoteInit.java#461

```
    /**
     * Finish remaining work for the newly forked system server process.
     */
    private static void handleSystemServerProcess(
            ZygoteConnection.Arguments parsedArgs)
            throws ZygoteInit.MethodAndArgsCaller {
....
            ClassLoader cl = null;
            if (systemServerClasspath != null) {
                cl = new PathClassLoader(systemServerClasspath, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
                Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(cl);
            }
            /*
             * Pass the remaining arguments to SystemServer.
             */
            RuntimeInit.zygoteInit(parsedArgs.targetSdkVersion, parsedArgs.remainingArgs, cl);
```

Comment: Do you mean I should use system class loader to load the class. Then I use the following code ClassLoader classloader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
            classloader.loadClass("com.android.server.BatteryService"); It is also failed due to ClassNotFound exeception. Perhaps I have to try install the app in /system/app as cgarrido said.

Answer (score 0):

As answered before, the classloader can't found the class. This is because the scope of the package is invisible if you don't have system's permissions (your apk should be installed in /system/app).

I recommend you to read [this doc](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid reflection and use the service class BatteryManager.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html